# How to automatically fill in data by matching serial numbers in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vlookup

I have an excel file with two sheets. 
Sheet One is a list of products with specific information.
Sheet Two is a list of individual parts which are used in each product.
The only common data between these two is the name of the product and a product ID number.

Currently i am manually matching the serial numbers together before copying over the product information over to each individual part.

Is there a way to automatically do this? Hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you provide an example dummy data for us to work with? A screenshot would be very helpful.

Comment: Share some sample data with us (few Rows & Columns only) ,,, will help us to fix the issue!!

Comment: Please provide a sample about your problem, I think **SUMPRODUCT** will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a vlookup formula. See below.

Example:
=vlookup(A1, “sheet2” a2:d10, 3, false)

A1: this is the first cell value to compare.

Sheet2: This table is in sheet 2. A2:d10 is the beginning and end of said table.

3: column with the value you want to bring back or match.

“False”: an exact match

Google vlookup. You may find helpful examples.

Comment: Better add some sample data and command illustration  to justify your solution !!